# Why is creating a model taking so much space in VRAM?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to know what is loaded in VRAM when creating a new model. Even in simple cases like:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(1,))])
```

memory usage increases from 0 to 4000+ MiB the moment I run the model definition command. Only thing that comes to my mind is that various CUDA libraries are loaded in memory, but I am not sure about that. Any thoughts?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow has a habit of taking as much space as it can incase it needs it later on. You can try the following to allow dynamic memory growth which should fix your issue.

```
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for i in physical_devices:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(i, True)
```